# How to assign Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles and Authenticatable to different models with Laravel

Tags: laravel, rbac, laravel-permission

There are 2 models:

User & Account

Each user has several accounts with different roles (one-to-many relation).

The User is Authenticatable

```
User extends Authenticatable
```

The AccountUser has roles trait.

```
AccountUser {
    use \Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
```

I assign roles to Account:

```
$account->assignRole('writer');
```

Now I want middleware to use Account instead of User model for check the permissions

```
['middleware' => ['permission:publish articles']
```

The question is: how to stay User Authenticatable and make AccountUser Roleble at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can you middleware in array :

```php
'middleware' => ['first','second']
```

That'll check both at time same time.

Your route middleware may be like this:

```php
'middleware' => ['role:writer','permission:publish articles']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the question is how to make it to check "rolecheck" of the NOT Authenticatable model (just related to the Authenticatable). At the same time "auth" should still work with Authenticatable.

There should be a way to setting it up.

Comment: you need rolecheck middleware i.e `is_writer` ?

Comment: now I got your idea - always use intermediate middleware instead of direct default, thanks :)

Comment: check my edit code , about more [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/middleware)